# Overwriting abstract method in partial class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, partial-classes, auto-generate

I have an abstract class named `PersonAbstract`. It has an abstract property called `Age`

```
abstract public int Age { get; set; }
```

Two classes called `Customer` and `Employee` extend `PersonAbstract` .

`Customer` and `Employee` are created using Linq-to-SQL, therefore they have auto-generated code.

The auto-generated code for both of these:

```
public int Age
{
   get
   {
      return this._age;
   }
   set
   {
      this._age = value;
   }
}
```

I add functionality to `Employee` and `Customer` using a partial class.

```
public partial class Employee: PersonAbstract
{
.....
```

How do I change this structure so that the inherited classes (`Employee` and `Customer`) have their person property overriding the person property in the abstract class without touching the auto-generated code?

Edit:

The issue is that I want to have both classes share some parent class's code. So I have been trying to add the abstract class with the shared code between the interface that implements that has the `Age` property and the two child classes. But that code needs access to the `Age` property. So the abstract class has to implement the interface using abstract instances of the `Age` property and the child classes override that. If this is not possible, how else can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't - the autogenerated code isn't using `override`, therefore it can't override the existing member.

If you put the age property into an *interface* though, then the auto-generated code would happily implement the interface for you.

Comment: Thanks, it is actually in an interface already. The issue is that I want to have both classes share some parent class's code. So I have been trying to add the abstract class between the interface and the two child classes.  But that code needs access to the Age property. So the abstract class has to implement the interface using abstract instances of the Age property and the child classes override that.  How else can I achieve this?

Comment: @user277498: It's pretty horrible, but you could make the abstract class *cast* `this` to the interface type when you needed to use its members, and then make the partial class derive from the abstract class and implement the interface. The constructor could check that `this` really implements the interface, and throw an exception if not. It does feel like there should be a better way... have you explored all the options in the designer for telling the code generator about the base class, and to add the overrides?

Comment: Yes, for each property the designer has a InheritanceModifier that can be set to override.  That seems to be working. Thanks!

Comment: @user277498: that's the way then, yes. Much nicer than the interface version with casting.

Comment: As of C# version 9, this now is possible! It will generate a compiler error when it is not abstracted in a non-partial class and an error when it's not implemented in any of your partial classes.

Answer (score 3):

I want to expand on my comment on Jon Skeet's answer. As of C# 9, [the rules for partial methods have been relaxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/extending-partial-methods) because of the introduction of [source generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/). This was my use case. I have a method declared as `abstract` that I want to implement via a source generator because it is incredibly repetitive to write.

```cs
public class DomainEvent
{
    public int Version;
}

public abstract class Aggregate
{
    public abstract string Id { get; }
    
    // This is the method I want to automatically generate through a source generator
    protected abstract void Route(DomainEvent @event);
}


public partial class Inventory : Aggregate
{
    public override string Id => "42";
}

public partial class Inventory 
{
    protected override void Route(DomainEvent @event)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```